# appending timeouts to asynchronous requests in WinRT

Tags: c#, exception, windows-runtime, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using this piece of code to append a TimeOut to a request call that I'm making to ensure that we don't encounter a slow internet connection - and that its handled appropriately.
When I DO meet the timeout condition I get an error message that I've been unable to fix within the extended function.

How to go about this task in general?

Code:

```
public static class SOExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(this Task<T> task, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            bool b = task.Wait(duration);
            if (b) return task.Result;
            return default(T);
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var response = await HttpWebRequest
                     .Create(request)
                     .GetResponseAsync()
                     .WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

I handle `AggregateException` with this (and through a `WebException`), but it still generates `AggregateException` when the timeout fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `CancellationToken` for timeouts (`new CancellationTokenSource(myTimeSpan).Token`), which you can then use *within* your `async` methods (e.g., for `HttpClient`, you pass the token to the `GetAsync` method). This takes up fewer resources because the HTTP request itself is canceled.

But if you want an "external" timeout, a more natural approach would be this:

```
public static async Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(this Task<T> task, TimeSpan duration)
{
  var timeout = Task.Delay(duration);
  var completeTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeout);
  if (completeTask == timeout)
    return default(T);
  else
    return await task;
}
```

This will prevent the exceptions from being wrapped into an `AggregateException`. It's not as efficient as the `CancellationToken` approach, though, which would look like this:

```
var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(uri, timeout.Token);
```

Note that the `CancellationToken` approach will throw `OperationCanceledException` instead of returning a `default(T)` if there is a timeout.

Comment: Worked very well, thanks. I'll try the CancellationToken bit in the next sprint, and report on it back here.

Comment: didn't actually work for me. it doesnt time out anymore, and claims I've not handled WebException even though I have done so. will try out the second method and then tag the answer

Comment: CancellationToken is the way to go, too bad its not that clear when you search online. thanks Stephen.

Comment: Stephen: Using a CancellationToken for timeouts with HttpClient.GetAsync only works as expected if the CancellationToken timeout is less HttpClient.Timeout. This is somewhat annoying design decision, and has been the source of confusion and quite a few bugs that I've seen, but one that I suspect is unlikely to change.